# Relay HTTPS requests without decrypting

Tags: c#, .net, https, network-programming, tcpclient

I am trying to modify existing open source proxy server, in .NET using c#, to be able to decrypt only specific web request and relay others without decrypting. 
I have `TcpListener` object which is used to accepts `TcpClients`.

```
var _listener = new TcpListener(ListeningIpAddress, ListeningPort);
_listener.Start();
_listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnAcceptConnection, _listener);
```

`OnAcceptConnection` method :

```
private static void OnAcceptConnection(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
  try{ 
    _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnAcceptConnection, _listener);
    var client = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyn);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => HandleClient(client));
  }
  catch{}
}
```

`HandleClient` method :

```
private static void HandleClient(TcpClient client)
{// No implementation}
```

i am trying to implement `HandleClient` method to relay accepted request  **to another proxy**  without decrypting. 
Please give me a suggestions.

Comment: TCP encompases HTTP and SSL.  SSL is a type of TCP just like HTTP is a type of TCP.  TCP itself doesn't have a direct encryption method, there are manual libraries that you can use to encrypt the data on one side and unencrypt it on the other (Maybe PGP?).  So there is nothing being automatically unencrypted on your side for which you could "not decrypt it".  If it appears to come to you unencrypted, then it was never encrypted to begin with.

Comment: @Suamere Thanks. by 'decryption`  i mean creating `SslStream` from `client.GetStream`  and then call `AuthenticateAsServer` on it. which requires Certificate, after which i can read from that stream non encrypted data. I am searching a method to avoid creating `SslStream` instead just sending content of `client.GetStream` to target.

Comment: Ah, there it is.  Thanks for the detail.